# Laravel custom store mthod not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am intergrating paypal payment gateway on my application, before user first leave my site for paypal, I saved all the necessary information, and set `payment_status` to be `0`, when user returns, if payment is sucessful, it returns to a new page where it gets the `paymentId`, and `payerID`, plus sets the `paymentstatus` to `1`.

the thing is that if i set the database value for `paymentID` and `PaymentId` to `null`, it doesnt save.

if i dont set it to anything i.e leave it blank, it would save, but retruns an error:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'PayerID' cannot be null (SQL: update `paypal_officers` set `paymentId` = , `PayerID` = , `updated_at` = 2018-07-15 07:29:21 where `id` = 1)
```

i cant seem to figure out what the problem is.

Here is the method that does the saving.

```
public function getPaymentStatus(Input $input)
{
    /** Get the payment ID before session clear **/
    $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');

    $insert_the_user_id = PaypalOfficer::findorFail(\session()->get('receivers_main_info_id'));
    $insert_the_user_id->update([
        'paymentId' => Input::get('paymentId'),
        'PayerID' => Input::get('PayerID'),
        'payment_status' => 1,
    ]);
    $insert_the_user_id->save();

    /** clear the session payment ID **/
    Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');

    if (empty(Input::get('PayerID')) || empty(Input::get('token'))) {
        \Session::put('error', 'Payment failed');
        return Redirect::to('account/send-money/paypal/send')->with('payer_id', $payment_id);;
    }

    $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);
    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId(Input::get('PayerID'));
    /**Execute the payment **/
    $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);

    if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
        \Session::put('success', 'Payment success');
        return Redirect::to('account/send-money/paypal/stagged/paypal')->with('payer_id', $result);
    }

    \Session::put('error', 'Payment failed');
    return Redirect::to('account/send-money/paypal/send');
}
```

My Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PaypalOfficer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'payment_status',
        'paymentId',
        'PayerID',
        'user_id',
        'amount',
        'destination_account_number',
        'destination_account_name',
        'destination_bank_name',
        'destination_phone_number',
        'destination_country',
        'destination_state',
        'currency_symbol',
        'receivers_name',
    ];
    //
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Please what must i be missing in the code , anybody please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occurs when `Input::get('PayerID')` is `empty` or `null`. You must be firstly check all required field exists in input, then try to update PaypalOfficer. Also in eloquent model use `->update` method that case `->save` does not need. 
Fix this part

```
public function getPaymentStatus(Input $input)
{
    // firstly check PayerID and paymentId input exist
    if (empty(Input::get('PayerID')) || empty(Input::get('paymentId')) || empty(Input::get('token'))) {
        \Session::put('error', 'Payment failed');
        return Redirect::to('account/send-money/paypal/send')->with('payer_id', $payment_id):
    }

    /** Get the payment ID before session clear **/
    $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');

    $insert_the_user_id = PaypalOfficer::findorFail(\session()->get('receivers_main_info_id'));
    $insert_the_user_id->update([
        'paymentId' => Input::get('paymentId'),
        'PayerID' => Input::get('PayerID'),
        'payment_status' => 1,
    ]);

    /** clear the session payment ID **/
    Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
```

Comment: ooh, silly me, how come I never figured that out, thank you sir davit. I really appreciate.